# How to speed up planar to packed/interleaved graphics in C++?

Tags: c++, graphics, arm, inline-assembly

I'm trying to program an Arduino Due to PWM a LED matrix. I need to ready the data before drawing each line, but the most inner loop in the process is too slow. The screen currently flickers. The loop should finish below 500us. The Arduino has a 84MHz Cortex-M3 ARM processor.

This is the concept of how I need to reassemble the bits for output:

5-bit color data:

```
R1=12, G1=4, B1=7, R2=0, G2=2, B2=27
```

The next step is to create a 32-bit stream of consecutive 1s. The number of 1s is given by the color value:

```
r1 = 0b00000000000000000000111111111111
g1 = 0b00000000000000000000000000001111
b1 = 0b00000000000000000000000001111111
r2 = 0b00000000000000000000000000000000
g2 = 0b00000000000000000000000000000011
b2 = 0b00000111111111111111111111111111
```

The last step is to reassemble every n-th bit of 10 pixels (total of 30 color values) into a 32-bit integer:

```
pack1 = 0b00 ... 111011
pack2 = 0b00 ... 111011
pack3 = 0b00 ... 111001
pack4 = 0b00 ... 111001
pack5 = 0b00 ... 101001
...
```

This is the code:

```
  // In my case scanwidth is 64*2 (64 is the width of the LED matrix and two lines are scanned at once)
  for ( i=0; i<scanwidth/5; i++) { // each run uses 5 upper and 5 lower pixels
      data = *lineptr++; // each int in the line buffer contains 2*15-bit inverted color data (red = 31-red etc.)
      p1uR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 26); // pixel 1 of upper line red channel
      p1uG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 21 & 0b11111);
      p1uB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 16 & 0b11111);
      p1lR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 10 & 0b11111);
      p1lG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 5  & 0b11111);
      p1lB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data  & 0b11111);
      data = *lineptr++;
      p2uR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 26);
      p2uG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 21 & 0b11111);
      p2uB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 16 & 0b11111);
      p2lR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 10 & 0b11111);
      p2lG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 5  & 0b11111);
      p2lB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data  & 0b11111);
      data = *lineptr++;
      p3uR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 26);
      p3uG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 21 & 0b11111);
      p3uB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 16 & 0b11111);
      p3lR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 10 & 0b11111);
      p3lG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 5  & 0b11111);
      p3lB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data  & 0b11111);
      data = *lineptr++;
      p4uR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 26);
      p4uG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 21 & 0b11111);
      p4uB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 16 & 0b11111);
      p4lR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 10 & 0b11111);
      p4lG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 5  & 0b11111);
      p4lB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data  & 0b11111);
      data = *lineptr++;
      p5uR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 26);
      p5uG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 21 & 0b11111);
      p5uB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 16 & 0b11111);
      p5lR = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 10 & 0b11111);
      p5lG = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data >> 5  & 0b11111);
      p5lB = 0x7FFFFFFF >> (data  & 0b11111);

      index = i;
      for (j=0; j<31; j++){ // loop over all 30 bits
          index += (scanwidth/5+1);
          scanbuff[index] = (p5uR>>j&1)<<29 | (p5uG>>j&1)<<28 | (p5uB>>j&1)<<27 | (p5lR>>j&1)<<26 | (p5lG>>j&1)<<25 | (p5lB>>j&1)<<24 
                          | (p4uR>>j&1)<<23 | (p4uG>>j&1)<<22 | (p4uB>>j&1)<<21 | (p4lR>>j&1)<<20 | (p4lG>>j&1)<<19 | (p4lB>>j&1)<<18 
                          | (p3uR>>j&1)<<17 | (p3uG>>j&1)<<16 | (p3uB>>j&1)<<15 | (p3lR>>j&1)<<14 | (p3lG>>j&1)<<13 | (p3lB>>j&1)<<12 
                          | (p2uR>>j&1)<<11 | (p2uG>>j&1)<<10 | (p2uB>>j&1)<<9  | (p2lR>>j&1)<<8  | (p2lG>>j&1)<<7  | (p2lB>>j&1)<<6 
                          | (p1uR>>j&1)<<5  | (p1uG>>j&1)<<4  | (p1uB>>j&1)<<3  | (p1lR>>j&1)<<2  | (p1lG>>j&1)<<1  | (p1lB>>j&1);
         }
     }
```

I don't think it's necessary to improve the outer loop. I did try to unroll the inner loop, but it didn't improve noticeably.

The  Cortex-M3 can do shifts and logic in one clock cycle. I estimate the outer and inner loop to take around 51000 clock cycles (600us).

Is there anything I can improve with standard C++ code? Are there any improvements that can be done in inline-assembly?

Comment: What about `#pragma unroll [(n)]` before the inner loop?

Comment: Another approach, which might be faster: create immediately the output (avoiding the transpose step)! I mean, you could have a function, which operates on scanbuff directly. For example, for p5uR, it could set 32-integers' 29th bit to 0 or 1, depending on the 5-bit value. Even, you could have 32 functions, for each value of a pixel, to avoid conditionals. So, for example, `set_0` function would set all the 32-bit integers' 29th bit to zero. `set_3` would set the first 3 32-bit integers' 29th bit to one, and to zero for the others. `set_31` would set all the 32-bit integers 29th bit to one, etc

Comment: Can you add types of variables to question?

Comment: Do you even use the values generated in the outer loop, like `p1uR`, other than as input to the inner loop? If not, you should just try to generate the final transposed value directly, and not generate the `00000011111` type values at all. For example, you could use a small lookup table taking the "saturated" value of the input color data and directly convert it into the various packed data representations.

Comment: I would suggest changing the code that sends the PWM signal so you don't have to generate this sort of data structure, but I don't know the details of how you are sending the PWM.

Comment: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4203.html Bit-banding to the rescue, I guess? Cortex-M 3/4 is really great at transforming a bit matrix at virtually zero cost.

Comment: bit-banding is optional feature, so make sure your chip supports it.  a disassembly of this code would be useful.  At 84mhz it is unlikely that you are running at one instruction per, some caching (st for example has their own that you cant turn off) may improve it but the flashes are usually much slower than the max speed of the cpu, like 20 or 30mhz and wait states are required, some the flash is half the speed the fastest it goes and wait states make it that much slower, so some performance measurements are in order here, dont assume.

Comment: I think it might be faster to convert that outer loop into a table lookup based on 15-bits of data.  Depending on how much ROM/RAM space you have, that is not too big of a table and removes a lot of bit twiddling.  Basically convert data into a 15-bit number and load your values in upper then lower.  Should cache well too and the compiler may remove a lot of temp vars with just table offsets in the inner loop, reducing register spillage.  Also, the intrinsic `clz` instruction and its cousins could speed things up a lot as well.

Comment: check your flash wait states (EEFC_FMR FWS bits) and see if they have it set for 4 cycles (3) or 5 cycles (4).

Comment: running this code from ram may make it run up to 4 times faster.

Comment: @DavidGrayson I made several implementations of different techniques. This one has a good contrast with a 5-bit grayscale. But I'm not using it anymore, because I made another one with 8-bit grayscale and similar contrast but which is much faster. I can now use 5-bit color values and convert them to 8-bit grayscale. I think I can even go up to a 9-bit or 10-bit.

Comment: @old_timer Isn't the code temporarely put into RAM?

Answer (score 6):

Time for some Cortex-M 3 black magic.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>
#include <cstring>

volatile char *const bitband_packed = (volatile char*)0x20000000;
volatile uint32_t *const bitband_exploded = (volatile uint32_t*)0x22000000;

static inline void transform_32_32(uint32_t buff[32]) {
    const std::size_t size = sizeof(buff[0])*32;
    volatile char *const tmp = bitband_packed;
    std::memcpy(const_cast<char*>(tmp), buff, size);
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        for(std::size_t j = i + 1; j < 32; j++) {
            std::swap(bitband_exploded[(32 * i + j)], bitband_exploded[(32 * j + i)]);
        }
    }
    std::memcpy(buff, const_cast<char*>(tmp), size);
}

void transform_pwm_32channel_5bit(const uint8_t input[32], uint32_t output[32]) {
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
        output[i] = 0xffffffff >> input[i];
    }
    transform_32_32(output);
}
```

The Cortex-M series has a nice feature called [Bit-Banding](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337h/Behcjiic.html). This allows for a quite efficient bitwise matrix transform, which is coincidentally exactly what you need to bitbang efficiently.

The transform should perform in about ~3 cycles per bit ([compiled on GCC 6.3 with -funroll-loops](https://godbolt.org/g/HJoz8A)), so this should amount for only about 12k cycles in total, or around 150us.

The only catch? This assumes that your specific Cortex-M 3 actually supports the Bit-Band feature. I had no chance to test this on an Arduino.

Comment: Bitbanding is fairly elegant, but your loop is still 32x32 iterations and bitbanding will not reduce the memory overhead, only the CPU effort.  It is probably better to place multiple bits at one time.  For instance, R1&0x5555555 | (G1<<1) & 0xAAAAAAAA has R1 and G1 combined for two bit extraction to the final 32 values.  At some point after combining several bits (four?), they can be extracted to form a final word.  Probably 8 registers/working combine values with extras registers for constants would be the best inner loop structure for an ARM/Thumb?  Cached output could be placed by bytes.

Comment: @artlessnoise It's only 32x15 iterations, the matrix is mirrored in place and the diagonal is skipped. Two loads, two stores, and some integer arithmetic to get the index right. <25 cycles to swap two bits each, already accounting for pipeline stalls from load / store / branch. Even if you do 4 bits at a time, with hand crafted Thumb instructions, you are hardly getting much lower than that.

Comment: It could be 32xln32 or 32x5 which is three times faster.  Also, I think that there would be much less loads/stores as the bit banding is re-reading and re-writing the values many times.  Registers should perform much faster.  I believe the OP will be memory bound, and not CPU bound... but both are always factors. Btw, if bit banding is fast enough for the OP, then problem solved!  I am just saying that there is likely something still faster.

Comment: I can't quite follow your numbers. I forgot to mention that my matrix has a size of 64*64. But even when assuming its width is only 32 pixels, the scanwidth would be 64, because it scans two lines at once (upper and lower). That makes 64*3 bits per PWM unit and a total of 64*3*31 bits (32nd bit is off) to prepare for output. With 11 cycles per bit that's 65k cycles or 780us. With my 64*64 matrix it's double the cylces and therefore 1560us, which is more than my current implementation!

Comment: @uzumaki Just an idea, but the IO ports are bit-banded as well. And the bit-band can not only be accessed by code, but also by the DMA controller. If your specific Arduino has one, you can use that to directly transfer all PWM words with the correct timing directly onto the IO ports, via bit-band. See e.g. https://sites.google.com/site/luiselectronicprojects/projects/rgb-matrix/ws2812-dma-ping-pong-mode Still going to leave that answer here as a reference how the bit-band works at all, even when access from code it far less efficient than required.

Comment: Note that only **some** of the Cortex-M series implement bit-banding.

Comment: @Ext3h For sending PWM data I think the bit field instruction is a better solution. But Bit-Banding could indeed work for packing the data, because I have to pack it bit by bit anyway. I will try to implement the technique in the following days and when it improves performance, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @uzumaki I had forgotten to pass "-funroll-loops" to GCC when doing the original run time estimation. So it's not 25 cycles per swap, but rather just <=6 cycles for the fully unrolled, and <=8 cycles for the partially unrolled iterations. At effectively ~3 cycles per bit, this should be able to compete with your implementation. Without enabling unrolling, the load / store latencies were responsible for the majority of the cost.

Comment: @Ext3h Bitbanging did indeed speed up the process by a small margin. But after improving on my first approach, it beats bitbanging by far. But I changed my method. Now I need to group the RGB bits the follwing way: 987654321098765432109876543210 -> 999888777666555444333222111000. One masking and one multiplication groups 3 bits. After grouping, I need to create integers made of 10 first groups, 10 2nd groups etc. Inline assembly can speed it up, but it's tricky because the registers are limited. I need 10 registers for 10 pixels, then the mask, magic number, interm. result and result.